# Why the raycast is drawn the raycast in opposite direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        int layerMask = 1 << 8;

        RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (Physics.Raycast(hand.transform.position, hand.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(hand.transform.position, hand.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.red);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(hand.transform.position, hand.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.yellow);
        }
    }
```

The hand is pointing the cube the but the raycast is pointing the opposite direction.

[image: Raycast opposite cirection]

Above the hand child object I added an empty GameObject and rest it to 0,0,0 for pos and rot.
Then dragged the hand to be child of it.
Then I'm shooting the raycast from the empty GameObject and yet the raycast is in the opposite direction.

This is the full code script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]

public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InteractableItem[] lookObj = null;
    public Text text;
    public float weightDamping = 1.5f;
    public float maxDistance = 10f;
    public bool RightHandToTarget = false;
    public GameObject hand;

    private Animator animator;
    private InteractableItem lastPrimaryTarget;
    private float lerpEndDistance = 0.1f;
    private float finalLookWeight = 0;
    private bool transitionToNextTarget = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (lookObj != null)
        {
            InteractableItem primaryTarget = null;
            float closestLookWeight = 0;

            // Here we find the target which is closest (by angle) to the players view line
            foreach (InteractableItem target in lookObj)
            {
                Vector3 lookAt = target.transform.position - transform.position;
                lookAt.y = 0f;

                // Filter out all objects that are too far away
                //if (lookAt.magnitude > maxDistance) continue;
                if (lookAt.magnitude > target.distance) continue;

                float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0f, transform.forward.z).normalized, lookAt.normalized);
                float lookWeight = Mathf.Clamp(dotProduct, 0f, 1f);
                if (lookWeight > 0.1f && lookWeight > closestLookWeight)
                {
                    closestLookWeight = lookWeight;
                    primaryTarget = target;
                }
            }

            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                if ((lastPrimaryTarget != null) && (lastPrimaryTarget != primaryTarget) && (finalLookWeight > 0f))
                {
                    // Here we start a new transition because the player looks already to a target but
                    // we have found another target the player should look at
                    transitionToNextTarget = true;
                }
            }

            // The player is in a neutral look position but has found a new target
            if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
                //finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, closestLookWeight, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 1f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.7f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);
                }
            }

            // Let the player smoothly look away from the last target to the neutral look position
            if ((primaryTarget == null && lastPrimaryTarget != null) || transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 0f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.7f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                if (finalLookWeight < lerpEndDistance)
                {
                    transitionToNextTarget = false;
                    finalLookWeight = 0f;
                    lastPrimaryTarget = null;
                }
            }

            // Show found object by the player
            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                text.text = primaryTarget.description;
            }
            else
            {
                text.text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        int layerMask = 1 << 8;

        RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (Physics.Raycast(hand.transform.position, hand.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(hand.transform.position, hand.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.red);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(hand.transform.position, hand.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.yellow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to output the actual value of `hand.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)` to the debug output?

Comment: Is the hand's parent object actually facing forward?

Answer (score 0):

Vector3.forward will aways show in the z direction. So in de editor it is the direction the blue arrow is pointing at.

So first thing is to check if the z (blue arrow) is pointing to the cube when selecting this hand object you mentioned. Make sure you toggled this setting to local before checking.

(screenshot below)

[image: Set this to local]

Also check the pivot of `hand.transform.position` because this is the startpoint of the ray cast. I had some problems with objects and models where the pivot point was out of center. So maybe this causes the problem